# why my git bash root command not working?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, nestjs, typeorm, pm2

I uploaded nodejs project using nestjs and typeform to awsec2 and used pm2 startnpm -- start command.

My server is working well now.

Since then, however, the pm2 command has not been heard at all and the pm2 input speed has been very slow.

Why did this happen?

[image]

Comment: What is the output of the `w` command? Any significant load on the server? If yes, what is the output of `iostat` if you have it installed and also `ps ax` - any zombie processes?

Comment: dear petrch
I solved the problem with your help. Thank you!

Comment: great to hear that!